# Disabling default mouse sensitivity

Tags: drivers, mouse

I just bought a new Razer Deathadder. I love the increased sensitivity through the driver I downloaded with it where I can customize exactly what DPI I want for my mouse. What I want to know is how I disable the system's mouse sensitivity found when I search mouse and it pops up with how much sensitivity you want. I figured installing the driver would disable this for my mouse. Instead it does affect the mouse. How do I disable this from affecting my new mouse?

Comment: What is the OS?

Answer (score 0):

it is obvious you are using windows,

what is the question?, is the mouse sensitivity settings not working for your new driver ( ie being over-ridden by the default mouse settings?

Would you not consider downloading the synaptics drivers instead? from here -->
[Synaptics pointing device](http://www.synaptics.com/resources/drivers/).

Comment: No, the driver software specific to the mouse is great. I would like to disable the default windows sensitivity. I want to know how to get rid of the default mouse settings as I'm not sure if it is messing with my mouse. Because when I went to test if it affected the new mouse changing the sensitivity there... it did.